# Integration of FedEx SOAP WS with Spring Restful WS Project

Tags: java, spring, soap, fedex, spring-rest

I want to integrate FedEx WS with Spring Restful WS project. FedEx uses SOAP protocol and am new to this SOAP.

I want to know how to integrate with Spring Restful WS . Is there any API available to call the SOAP endpoints

Any thoughts on this or any resources available

Comment: which web service is the client and which one is server ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use MuleSOFT ESB to change from one form of webservice to another.

You can look at Mule [here](https://www.mulesoft.org/what-mule-esb).

What you can do is consume a SOAP service using MULE. Then convert it to JSON using MULE. And then serve up the data as RESTful API. You can find everything in Mule.